# Flask-WTF, how to dynamically set values of SelectField in a Form, and append it to FieldList

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

How to append SelectField values to a FieldList?

I want to set the `label` and `choices` dynamically. It does *append* the SelectField, but the populated data `variation_form = VariationForm(field_name="Size", choices=[("small", "Small")])` remains empty.

```
class VariationForm(FlaskForm):
    """Product Variations Form."""

    def __init__(self, field_name=None, choices=[], *args, **kwargs):
        """Initialize Form."""
        form = super(VariationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        form.field.choices = choices  # This don't work
        form.field.label = field_name # Also this don't work

    field = SelectField()


class ProductDescriptionForm(FlaskForm):
    """Product Description Form."""

    variations = FieldList(FormField(VariationForm))
```

```
@bp.route("/product", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def product_description():
    """Product Details Route."""
    form = ProductDescriptionForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        pass

    variation_form = VariationForm(field_name="Size", choices=[("small", "Small")])  # This part fails
    form.variations.append_entry(variation_form)

    return render_template("public/product_details/index.jinja", form=form)
```

## **UPDATE**

Strangely, this part what really fails:

```
variation_form = VariationForm(field_name="Size", choices=[("small", "Small")])
```

Because when I tried setting the value in the `__init__`, it does assign the value properly, but it doesn't work when calling the `VariationForm(field_name="Sample Label")` inside the views.py:

```
class VariationForm(FlaskForm):
    """Product Variations Form."""

    def __init__(self, field_name="Sample Label", choices=[], *args, **kwargs):
        """Initialize Form."""
        form = super(VariationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        form.field.choices = choices  # This don't work
        form.field.label = field_name # This now works

    field = SelectField()
```

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, shouldn't you have a SelectField in VariationForm?  Something like this perhaps: size = SelectField(label='Size',
                            choices=[("small", "Small"), ("large", "Large")])

Comment: @Ben, I have a database that has different variants per Product. Some products don't have size variant, some do need Color variant. That's why I need to create select fields dynamically. I just put a pre-populated variant to test if it works.

Comment: I found out, this is not possible with normal FieldList(). I have to create a Custom Field to handle dynamic & multiple SelectField()

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. Thanks for the update! Best of luck with your project.